# Using NGINX mod_zip inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, zip

I'm trying to configure **NGINX** with this dynamic module inside a **Docker container**, and in [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/nginx/comments/9jzqa6/trying_to_understand_mod_zip/) I found a way (maybe, but I'm not sure) to implement **mod_zip** using a reverse_proxy inside the `nginx.conf` file.

But I'm having an issue when trying to access the file server through the **port 80**, it returns the following error message:

```
[error] 30#30: *1 mod_zip: invalid file list from upstream while sending to client, client: 172.28.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

Can someone help me with this issue? And maybe provide me an example that could work using **NGINX** inside a **Docker container**

I'm going to share my configuration files, in order to give a better understanding of this process:

There you have the `Dockerfile` file, which use two stages for the build, one for compile the `hello_world_nginx` module (only for testing purposes) and other for compile the `mod_zip` module.

And also add some files inside the `files` directory into a previously created directory, which is called `/var/www` which is need to serve the files into NGINX, as a file server, and the files could be in any **uncompressed** format, an then be selected and downloaded into a **`zip`** format using the **mod_zip** module.

**`Dockerfile`**:

```
FROM nginx:1.25.2 AS build

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y build-essential \
                       wget \
                       git \
                       libpcre3 libpcre3-dev \
                       zlib1g zlib1g-dev \
                       openssl libssl-dev \ 
                       procps

RUN mkdir src

WORKDIR /src/

RUN wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.25.2.tar.gz

RUN tar -xzvf nginx-1.25.2.tar.gz

RUN git clone https://github.com/perusio/nginx-hello-world-module.git

RUN git clone https://github.com/evanmiller/mod_zip.git

RUN git clone --branch=patch-1 https://github.com/dvershinin/nginx-unzip-module.git

# * Hello world module.
RUN cd nginx-1.25.2/ && ./configure --with-compat --add-dynamic-module=../nginx-hello-world-module

RUN cd nginx-1.25.2 && make modules

RUN cd nginx-1.25.2 && cp objs/ngx_http_hello_world_module.so /etc/nginx/modules

# * Zip module.
RUN cd nginx-1.25.2/ && ./configure --with-compat --add-dynamic-module=../mod_zip

RUN cd nginx-1.25.2 && make modules

RUN cd nginx-1.25.2 && cp objs/ngx_http_zip_module.so  /etc/nginx/modules


#* Development stage. 
FROM nginx:1.25.2 AS development-stage

COPY --from=build /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_hello_world_module.so /etc/nginx/modules

COPY --from=build /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_zip_module.so /etc/nginx/modules

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/

COPY ./files /var/www

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx
```

Then, inside the configuration of the `nginx.conf` file  I have a statement to load the `hello_world_module`, only for testing purposes, and the `mod_zip` module.

When I use this `nginx.conf` file, it doesn't returns any error regarding the load of these modules, which seems to be right.

Then, inside the `http` block, I enable the `gzip` module, and define a `server` directive which is going to listen on `8080` port, and a location directive which is going to map the `/` path with the content inside the `/var/www` directory, which holds the **uncompressed** files that I need to display inside the file server, and then I need to be downloaded `compressed` with the `.zip` extension using the `mod_zip` module.

Finally, I define another `server` directive which is going to listen on `80` port and mapped the response of the first `server` directive. But, as I said, this not seems to be working.

**`nginx.conf`**:

```
load_module /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_hello_world_module.so;
load_module /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_zip_module.so;

worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    gzip on;

    gzip_types text/plain text/css
    application/json
    application/javascript
    text/xml
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    text/javascript;

    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;

        location / {
            # hello_world;
            root /var/www;
            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size on;
            autoindex_localtime on;

            add_header X-Archive-Files 'zip';

            # this line sets the name of the zip that the user gets
            add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename=example.zip';
            add_header Content-Type application/zip;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        location / {
            root /var/www;
            
            proxy_hide_header X-Archive-Files;

            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";

            proxy_pass_request_headers off;

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
    }
}
```